# Microsoft Office 365 Task or Todo php api authorization

Tags: php, office365

I want to implement some workflows, they should add some tasks to Microsoft todo app.

They have a rest api. I try to access the oauth. But have wrong return url. And I don't want to have a browser application it should be only a php script running in background.

I tried this:

```
$url = oAuthService::getLoginUrl("http://localhost/microsoftToDoTest/auth.php");

header("location:".$url);


class oAuthService {
    private static $clientId = "";
    private static $clientSecret = "";
    private static $authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com";
    private static $authorizeUrl = '/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=%1$s&redirect_uri=%2$s&response_type=code';
    private static $tokenUrl = "/common/oauth2/token";

    public static function getLoginUrl($redirectUri) {
        $loginUrl = self::$authority.sprintf(self::$authorizeUrl, self::$clientId, urlencode($redirectUri));
        error_log("Generated login URL: ".$loginUrl);
        return $loginUrl;
    }
}
```

What would be the correct way to authorize with php on the microsoft services?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking to your code and the documentation I would assume you need to request a token to create a valid session. Then supply that token over an url in a cookie with a session ID.

```
Route::get('/authorize', 'AuthController@gettoken');
```

Now in their documentation microsoft supplies this:

```
public function signin() 
{
  if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
  }

  // Initialize the OAuth client
  $oauthClient = new \League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider([
    'clientId'                => env('OAUTH_APP_ID'),
    'clientSecret'            => env('OAUTH_APP_PASSWORD'),
    'redirectUri'             => env('OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI'),
    'urlAuthorize'            => env('OAUTH_AUTHORITY').env('OAUTH_AUTHORIZE_ENDPOINT'),
    'urlAccessToken'          => env('OAUTH_AUTHORITY').env('OAUTH_TOKEN_ENDPOINT'),
    'urlResourceOwnerDetails' => '',
    'scopes'                  => env('OAUTH_SCOPES')
  ]);

  // Generate the auth URL
  $authorizationUrl = $oauthClient->getAuthorizationUrl();

  // Save client state so we can validate in response
  $_SESSION['oauth_state'] = $oauthClient->getState();

  // Redirect to authorization endpoint
  header('Location: '.$authorizationUrl);
  exit();
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/php-tutorial microsoft probably uses the same way all around office365. Hopefully this will help you implement the right code.

Comment: Yes I saw this and read it but don't really know how to implemenet it each time I run it a website opens to add the credentials. Thats not what I need. I need it as a deamon job on a server

Comment: Hi Felix, I was a little bizzy for a while, I was wondering if you figured it out yet.

Comment: I have a semi working solution right now. I can start the oAuth process. But got an error while verification ... didn't had time to check whats wrong